# C++ finalizer template

Tags: c++, c++11, template, variadic

Consider, please, my code of the finalizer template:

```
#include <functional>


template<typename F, typename... Args>
class finally
{
public:

  finally(F action, const Args&... args) :
      _action(std::bind(action, args...))
  {}
  ~finally()
  {
    if(enabled)
      _action();
  }

  bool enabled = true;

private:

  std::function<void()> _action;
};
```

In particular I would enhance this template to avoid of using a typenames twice. Let's say we need to close some file on leaving some block of code. Then we declare an object:

```
finally<int(int), int> f(close, some_file);
```

Here I used the standard `close` function as an action. But I should use `int` twice in the `<int(**int**), **int**>`. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid specifying argument types twice by employing a constructor template:

```
template<typename F>
class finally
{
public:
  template<typename... Args>
  finally<F>(F action, const Args&... args) { /* business as usual */ }
  ...
};
```

But that's not everything. The `std::bind`'s arguments are either copied or moved, they are never passed by reference. Thus, despite `const Args&... args`, you might end up copying your arguments.

To void this issue, consider using perfect forwarding (as well as ditching `std::bind`):

```
template<typename... Args>
finally<F>(F action, Args&&... args) :
    _action([action, &args...]{ action(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }) {}
```

Another thing worth considering is the exception safety of `action`. Since you're invoking it in a destructor, you're risking facing `std::terminate` if it throws. A small `try` block will fix it. Also, as of now, `enabled` seems redundant.

And yes, even with all these fixes, the semantics of `finally` seems rather unpleasant compared to [more traditional scope guards.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Scope_Guard) At least to me.

Edit: full code - https://ideone.com/iThn0i

Comment: The `enabled` is needed to manually switch off the finalizer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered something like,

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<FILE, int(*)(FILE*)> FileHandle;
FileHandle f {fopen("sample.txt"), fclose};
```

Of course, you need a typedef for every custom deleter you want to have. If you're looking for a generic finalizer then, you basically got what you wanted with a price of `std::function` on it.